# 405 error making axios put/patch request from vue to laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, vue.js, axios

Help me, I can't get update method working with put/patch.Also had no problem when it was `react`, so maybe `vue` has something to do wrong with it or maybe I miss simple something.

```
let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", this.image);
            formData.append("name", this.name);
            axios
                .post(
                    "/api/items/" + this.editId,
                    {
                        _method: 'patch',
                        data: formData,
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                        }
                    }
                )
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
```

I also tried

```
axios.put(
                    "/api/items/" + this.editId,
                    {
                        data: formData,
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                        }
                    }
                )
```

but then I got empty `$request` in update method in laravel's controller (id works)

this is how I define routes in my `api.php`

```
Route::apiResource('items', 'API\ItemsController');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535510/put-form-data-axios-vue-js/65382178#65382178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", this.image);
            formData.append("name", this.name);
     axios.
           put("/api/items/" + this.editId, {
                  params: {
                     data: formData
                },

                  headers: {
                       "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }

            })
            .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
{ 'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH' }
```

to specify the method you want.
example of the above code;

```
let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", this.image);
        formData.append("name", this.name);
        axios
            .patch(
                "/api/items/" + this.editId,
                {
                    data: formData,
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                        "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PATCH"
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
```