# PUT form-data axios vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I just updated my User model with "avatar" field so I can upload a photo. I used a PUT method already configured and just added avatar to it. In postman the file upload (form-data) it works just fine, but when trying to upload it using axios from vue.js it doesn't work. I tried in many ways, the last one, I tried to send the request as multi form data.

```
async saveChanges() {
      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("id", this.$auth.user().id);
      fd.append("username", this.$auth.user().username);
      fd.append("email", this.user.email);
      fd.append("firstName", this.$auth.user().firstName);
      fd.append("lastName", this.$auth.user().lastName);
      fd.append("isAdmin", this.$auth.user().isAdmin);
      fd.append("password", this.user.password);
      fd.append("confirmpass", this.user.confirmpass);
      fd.append("avatar", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
      fd.append("_method", "put");
      try {
        await this.axios.put(`/users/${this.$auth.user().id}`, {
          fd
        }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
}
```

After i choose the file, it is available, but I am unable to send it trough my method. Should i create another request just for updating the avatar or is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
axios.put('/users/${this.$auth.user().id', fd, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: hey, tried it. still not working. I also tried to pass this trough config

Comment: You wrote that you are unable to send a request with a file. What sort of problem have you faced? Did you catch any exceptions?

Comment: no, it's not throwing any error. try {
        await this.axios.put(`/users/${this.$auth.user().id}`, fd, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          }
        }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
but i'm not getting any res in console either. in postman i am able to put with form-data, but when trying from vue js it doesn't throw any error, i m getting my file correctly, i cant figure out what am i missing

Comment: im sending the data in the body

Comment: Well, what the response do you see on the Network tab in your DevTool, when you're sending the request. What status and response object are there?

Comment: hey, it worked after i checked the error. Firstly, because i was using the same method putUser for updating it, the password was required so that was one of the issues. You really helped me!

Answer (score 4):

> Pass your method as post method and define put in form data
> `formData.append('_method', 'PUT')` .

```
async handleSubmit() {

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', this.file);
      formData.append('title', this.form.title);
      formData.append('_method', 'PUT')

      try {
        const response = await axios.post(`image-update/${this.$route.params.id}`, formData)

        this.$router.push('/');
        console.log(response);
      } catch (e) {
        this.error = 'Something error found !';
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks thats work for me

Answer (score 0):

My previous wrong code that return empty result in `$request->all()`

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('message', 'AnyMessage')
```

Then I change it as follows and it's working fine -

```
let data = "message=AnyMessage"
```